# Powershell Terminology

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm a beginner in powershell and I get confused when reading tutorials about powershell. 
In powershell, does the term command refer to: 
a - The commands entered by the user in the command line or in scripts;
b - The applications, the functions and the cmdlets executed by powershell;
c - Both;

Comment: It would help us if we knew where you are coming from.  How much have you used the DOS shell?  How much have you used batch files  (.bat)?  Have you ever used bash, PHP, Python, etc?  We will help you most if we can relate what is unfamiliar to you to things you already know.

Comment: Could you please include the context in which a tutorial used the term? That way, we can better explain what it's trying to convey.

Comment: the term `command` is a little overloaded. At its most formal a command is a statement provided by a user, that the shell can understand. From that perspective an application/script/cmdlet is not a command, but the statement that invokes the applicaton/script/cmdlet is. that the script/cmdlet might be composed of commands is a matter of perspective, so it introduces some ambiguity. You will see usages of the term that indicate that edit.com is a command, and others that say typing `edit` into a dos shell is the command, or even the invocation of the edit command.

Answer (score 0):

C. The commands entered by the user in the command line or in scripts are the applications, functions and cmdlets that are executed by PowerShell. The applications, functions and cmdlets that are executed by PowerShell can be run as commands in scripts and the command line. For example, the command Copy-Item in PowerShell is a cmdlet that can be used in the PowerShell command line or in scripts to copy item(s) in a folder to another folder.

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714395(v=vs.85).aspx), a cmdlet is "a lightweight command that is used in the Windows PowerShell environment." (See the link for more on cmdlets) Unlike the commands that are used in Command Prompt (which, by the way, can be used in PowerShell), cmdlets are instances of .NET Framework classes; they are not stand-alone executables.

You can read more about cmdlets and PowerShell in the link above and at [Stackify](https://stackify.com/what-are-powershell-commands/). Search on Google for anything you need.